# Limit without using l'Hopital

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

How can I find  $$\lim_{n \to \infty}{n \cos(\pi/2 + 1/n)}$$ without using L'Hôpital's rule?

Using L'Hopital's rule I can find the answer to be -1, but without it I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 8):

**Hint:** 
$$\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{1}{n}\right)=\sin(?).$$

Answer (score 2):

HINT: $$\cos\left(\frac{\pi}2+\frac1n\right)=\cos\frac{\pi}2\cos\frac1n-\sin\frac{\pi}2\sin\frac1n\;;$$ what are $\cos\frac{\pi}2$ and $\sin\frac{\pi}2$?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**
$$\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}2+y \right) = - \sin \left(y \right)$$
and
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$$

Answer (score 1):

Put $m=\frac{1}{n}$, then

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}{n \cos(\pi/2 + 1/n)} =  \lim_{m \to 0}\frac{\cos(m+\pi/2 )}{m} =\dots $$